# Vuetify - Gallery

Tags: vue.js, gallery, vuetify.js

I am trying to make a gallery using vuetify.
That's my code

```
 data(){
    return{
      images:[
          {source: "require('../assets/image.jpg')", alt:"asd"},
          {source: "require('../assets/image01.jpg')", alt:"sds"},
          {source: "require('../assets/img-sydney.jpg')", alt:"asdf"}
      ]
    }
}

<v-row>
     <v-col v-for="n in 12" :key="n" cols="4">
        <v-img v-for="image in images" :key="image.alt" :src="image.source" :alt="image.alt"></v-img>
     </v-col> 
 </v-row>
```

The images are not showing, i am getting this error :[Vuetify] Image load failed

Can someone help me to understand the problem? is it a path problem? My images are inside the assets folder

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
data(){
    return{
      images:[
          {source: "require('@/assets/image.jpg')", alt:"asd"},
          {source: "require('@/assets/image01.jpg')", alt:"sds"},
          {source: "require('@/assets/img-sydney.jpg')", alt:"asdf"}
      ]
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add folder structure of your project?!

Comment: My images are inside src/assets. Inside src folder I have a components folder with all my components file, I did not move any folder , it is a new project just created using Vue cli.

Answer (score 0):

The src attribute should be string so remove the require() function:  `{source: "../assets/image.jpg", alt:"asd"}`